# How to make a custom file dialog control read-only?

Tags: winapi

I'm looking at custom dialog controls, which are added by using the [IFileDialogCustomize interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and I can see ways to do most of what I need, but there's one thing I don't see: How can I set a particular control to read-only status under certain circumstances?  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `SetControlState` (with flags for visible but disabled)?

Comment: @Manuell: This produces a disabled control, which is visually and functionally a very different thing.

Comment: Then maybe 2 controls and show/hide?